# score in SK Learn

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I am new to SK-Learn, when i'm evaluating the models, i use clf.score (X_test, y_test) (for a tree model for instance). I'm confused on what this score is. In the past, i was more used to talk about mean square error. I found the link http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html , but I really couldn't find any clear explanations. Please shine some lights. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to scikit learn [site](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html), for sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier, it should return the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.

You can find the corresponding code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/base.py#L263). Seems that score methods for classification problem returns accuracy and for regression method, it returns $R^2$.

Comment: Thanks, is 'Accuracy' same as mean square error? or how exact it's defined?

Comment: number of correct prediction divided by number of test data.